# schedule a Jmeter test in GUI mode.

Tags: jmeter, schedule

We want to schedule a Jmeter test in GUI mode.How can this be done. Can i run the test through power shell scripts. Please help.
Thanks and regards,
Theju

Comment: 0
down vote
favorite
We want to schedule a Jmeter test in GUI mode.How can this be done. Can i run the schedule through power shell scripts. Please help. Thanks and regards, Theju

Comment: Any feedback on answer ? Thanks

Comment: You want to open in specific time jmeter GUI and execute test automatically while GUI remains open?

Answer (score 1):

Up to JMeter 3.3, there is a possibility to use in Scheduler part:

- Start Time
- End Time

But don't use this way, it is removed in upcoming 3.4.

GUI mode is not made for Load Testing, only for script debugging.

You should schedule it using other external tools (Jenkins, OS Scheduler, CRON...) which will trigger it in NON GUI mode.

You just configure Scheduler in Thread Group:

[image]

You can then pass the duration property on Command line:

jmeter.bat(Windows)/jmeter.sh(Linux) -Jduration=3600 -n -t test-file -l results.csv -j jmeter.log -e -o [Path to output folder]